# What is the best algorithm so far for probabilistic adaptive group testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, optimal

I am checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing#Classification_of_group-testing_problems but could not figure out the answer.

I am focusing on probabilistic adaptive group testing. The problem is defined as given N items with the probability of defective item is `p`.

A binary test can be applied in an item or a set of items (any size) and return whether the set of items is defective or not. If the result is defective, it means at least one item in the set is defective, but we do not know what it is.

The goal is to detect all defective items by using the minimum of tests.

In literature so far, what is the best algorithm and what is the number of test?